# Is it possible to apply multiple discount codes to an event registration?

Tags: civievent, cividiscount

We have an event that has an early-bird discount and a separate discount for returning participants. I created 2 discount codes. Both work individually, but if I enter one and then the other, only the 2nd one is used. Is there a way to use both discounts?

Comment: no. Why not create a cumulative discount for scenario 1 and 2?

Comment: @kzburn you should post that as an answer!